# .NET Web App with Identity Server 4 to authenticate with SharePoint 2019 On-Prem over CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, identityserver4, csom

We have a situation where we are connecting to SharePoint 2019 using the current user logged in to authenticate (so no hard-coded username/password to pass over CSOM).  We do not use the SharePoint UI at all, so everything is done from Web App API to SharePoint 2019 API (via CSOM).

Our current Web Application is secured with Identity Server 4.  How can we get authentication working from .NET/CSOM in the Web Application's APIs to use the current user's identity to make the call to SharePoint 2019.

Currently, SharePoint's Authentication is just set to Negotiate/Kerberos, but I have a feeling that it needs to use Identity Server as the Trust Provider (as seen here: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/IdentityServer-4-SharePoint-Integration-using-WS-Federation)  The only issue is that this example is using the UI of SharePoint to prompt the logins, and isn't solely from API to API connects nor does it reference any examples of doing that via code.

Thanks in advance!